# how to make solution visible in solution explorer window of visual studio 2010 or visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

i am using visual studio2010. i am facing a problem that when i create a new web project then visual studio makes project and don't show its solution in solution explorer.
And the other thing is that i want to add a project with my existing web project how i can add it with this one, i just know to add another project by its solution right click. first please tell me how i can make solution visible for my existing projects that i made before and for other projects that i will create. [image: here i attach an image when i create a new project and i an example for another project where solution has shown]

Comment: just Make sure the Create directory for solution Checkbox is checked when you create a new project

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can make the solution always show by Options dialog
[image]

Comment: Well I'll be damned fair play ! you learn something everyday!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you should follow this link to create a new solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfzh36t7.aspx

It also tells you how to add existing projects to new solutions is well. There really isn't that much to it.

Your issue isn't you cannot see the solution. It is that you have created a project only and not a solution. So I would create a new solution and then add existing projects to it.

Also as mentioned by @Devjosh in the comments when creating a new project you can say create new solution with the checkbox.