# Upgrade Visual Studio 2013 solutions to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I have installed both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2015. Projects and solutions that were created in VS2013 are opened by VS2013 as I would expect, but I would like to be able to upgrade those files so that they would be opened by VS2015 when double clicked.

How can I upgrade solution files that are in VS2013 format so that the Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector will open them in VS2015?

Comment: After upgrading you may want to move the files to the 2015 Projects folder. If you use Team Foundation Server 2013 here are the steps for moving the source code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39022515/how-do-i-move-tfs-2013-code-to-a-new-local-working-folder-after-upgrading-soluti/39022713#39022713

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2012 doesn't convert vs2010 solution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095339/visual-studio-2012-doesnt-convert-vs2010-solution)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The simplest solution IMO (also worked for 2012 and 2013) is:

1. Open the solution file using Visual Studio 2015
2. Select the solution file in Solution Explorer
3. Select File / Save MySolution.sln As...
4. Overwrite the existing solution file.

Comment: You can't batch this solution

Comment: Note that I had to first highlight the solution itself in Solution Explorer before the expected `Save As` menu item showed up in the File menu.

Comment: Also make sure, that you really open the solution with Visual Studio 2015. I opened it with VS 2013 by accident and wondered why Save As didn’t change the Visual Studio version.

Comment: Also make sure, that you're highlighting the solution, like Sam said - I was on the website project node, not the solution node.

Comment: i have got vs2013 pro and vs2015 community .. i tried this answer it doesn't work for me .. when i open the solution file in note it can see it updated the visual studio version like in Zach answer below but when i double click on the solution again it just opens in vs2013 like before. is there anything else i should check?

Comment: This is basically the "official" way of doing what the answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31591633/67824) suggests. For now it makes the exact same changes, but there's no guarantee that won't change which is why it's preferable (barring batching needs).

Comment: File | Save works just fine, and avoids the unnecessary Save As dialog.

Comment: Anyone can't find the solution in the Solution Explorer, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9173460/8967612).

Answer (score 41):

Change the version in the .sln file

```
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.31101.0
```

To match whatever version you have

As of this morning my VS Enterprise is `14.0.23107.0`

Example:

```
# Visual Studio 2015
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.23107.0
```

---

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 is `14.0.25420.1`

Comment: I wasn't sure if Visual Studio needed to have any other changes, but this solution works and is a simple change. Thanks!

Comment: It should work to just change the comment: ``# Visual Studio 2015`` which is what the multi-selector triggers off of...

Comment: _"Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 is 14.0.25123.0"_, Nope, [that's Update 3](http://imgur.com/qyODpvs).

Comment: I'm upgrading from 2013 to 2017 and this solution worked for me

Answer (score 19):

**Note**: This works for VS 2015 and 2017

An alternative to hand-editing the .sln file or re-saving on top of the original .sln file:

1. Open the solution in Visual Studio
2. Right click solution > Add > New Solution Folder (name does not matter)
3. Save solution
4. Delete the newly added solution folder
5. Save solution

The solution will now be upgraded.

Comment: Fantastic and easy for VS2017.  Thanks.  That way Visual Studio changes the .sln file instead of me patching it.

Answer (score 8):

I ran across this looking for the same thing.  The accepted answer works, but I noticed some comments about not being batchable.  I found an option for batching and I thought I'd share.

You can use the `/upgrade` option in `devenv.com`.  This means it's batchable.  For example, to recurse the current directory upgrading all .sln files (after backing them up), you could do this:

```
dir -Recurse -path ".\" *.sln | ForEach-object {
    Copy-Item $_.FullName "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.Name.Remove($_.Name.Length - $_.Extension.Length)).vs2013$($_.Extension)";
    & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" /upgrade $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, good to know the IDE can do it from the command line. How fast is it?

Comment: Doesn't actually work for migration from VS2013 -> VS2015.  When running the /upgrade command, the message "This project/solution does not require migration. It will open without modification." is displayed, and the .SLN file is left unmodified.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the problem by this: Right click on solution, "Retarget solution".(vs2013)

Comment: That upgrades the projects too.

Comment: I can't find this option in Visual Studio 2015 (update 3)

Comment: This is correct answer for VS2017. In my case, one of the project that was set as startup was failing so I'd to set a different startup project (Python project works).

Answer (score 4):

The other solutions here didn't work for me. My project was created in Visual Studio 2012, and I am now using Visual Studio 2015, but this should work if you're going from 2013 to 2015. This is how you manually upgrade a project from a earlier version to a newer one:

1. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 (to find it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Type in `devenv SolutionFile | ProjectFile /upgrade` and press enter

Where `SolutionFile | ProjectFile` is the full path with filename of your .sln file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15a82ay.aspx