# How to set Visual Studio 2015 as the default editor for older projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Visual Studio 2015 is backwards compatible with 2013.  As a result, it doesn't upgrade solution files that you open with 2015 at all.

Now, I recently installed Visual Studio 2013 and whenever I open a solution (.sln) file, it uses the Visual Studio Version selector to pick Visual Studio 2013 *instead* of 2015.

How can I configure the Visual Studio Version Selector to use the highest valid version instead of the specific version indicated without necessarily modifying the .sln file (discussed here: [How to force a Solution file (SLN) to be opened in Visual Studio 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513306/how-to-force-a-solution-file-sln-to-be-opened-in-visual-studio-2013)).  I want to avoid breaking others who might not be using 2015 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you update .sln file to open with VS2015 by default, it will still work with VS2013. `MinimumVisualStudioVersion` parameter inside .sln will let users with VS2013 to open solution normally.

I prefer to update .sln files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589845/upgrade-visual-studio-2013-solutions-to-visual-studio-2015?lq=1).

1. Open solution you wish to upgrade in VS2015
2. Select the solution file in Solution Explorer
3. Select File / Save MySolution.sln As...
4. Overwrite the existing solution file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Find your project(.sln file), right click and select "properties".
2. Under "General" option, click "Change" button behind "Opens with" item.
3. Select "VS2015" then click OK. Done~