# How do I move TFS 2013 code to a new local working folder after upgrading solution to VS 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I've upgraded a VS 2013 solution to Visual Studio 2015 [using these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31648763/381082). Now I want to move the project from the Projects folder under VS 2013 to the VS 2015 Projects folder. The code is checked in to Team Foundation Server 2013. **What steps do I take to change the TFS working folder?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following

1. In VS 2015 (with no solution loaded) open Team Explorer at the Home section
2. In the "Solutions" section expand the drop-down beside "Workspace:" and select "Manage Workspaces..."
3. Select your workspace and click Edit
4. Point your working folder to wherever you want by clicking "..." in both the "Source Control Folder" and "Local Folder" column.
5. Answer Yes when prompted to get the latest files from version control to update your workspace.

Source files will be removed from the previous working folder and placed in the new working folder.